# css: overflowing side divs with vertical centered texts behave strange

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to create a header which contains 3 main elements centered on the page. On both sides of the 3 main divs i'd like to add another div which overflows the page by half it's width.[image]

Like so. Both red divs are twice the length as shown, but overflow:hidden cuts them off. 
This is easy enough to create but when i try to add the content of the blue diffs suddenly all of them slide down[image]
I don't understand why this happens.
Furthermore when i add some content to the side divs everything falls back into place[image]
So then i thought of just adding a nbsp; to the red divs to keep everything in position. Which worked. however when i try to center the content of the blue diffs vertically by adding a padding-top the red diffs move down for reasons unknown to me[image]

here  is my css

```
div.padded{
    padding-top:20px;
}
.header{
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid black;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.leftExtend{
    width:25%;
    margin-left:-12.5%;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
}
.middle{
    width:25%;
    background-color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
.rightExtend{
    width:25%;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="leftExtend">sometext</div>
    <div class="middle padded"><a href="#">aaa</a></div>
    <div class="middle padded"><a href="#">bbb</a></div>
    <div class="middle padded"><a href="#">ccc</a></div>
    <div class="rightExtend">sometext</div>
</div>
```

I created a  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bn7t403y/1/) to demonstrate the problem.

Why does this happen, what am i doing wrong and what would be the correct way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `vertical-align: top;` to the `div`s:

```
.header div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The default is baseline which causes them to appear at the bottom.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnay0ox4/)

Comment: yes that did the trick. thanks =). but if the default location of the diffs would be the bottom. Why are first and the third example working as i expected?

Comment: I think (someone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong!) baseline aligns to the bottom of text which would appear to be the case in the first and third examples.